# Using javascript to change <a> tag to use selected option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a select list within a modal using a PHP loop.

The options display properly,and upon inspecting elements they are showing the appropriate option value (pageID) as well:

```
<select name="pageToAssign">
     <?php foreach($activePages as $pages):?>
     <option value="<?php echo $pages['id']?>"><?php echo $pages['id']?><?php echo $pages['title']?></option>
     <?php endforeach?>
</select>
<a href="assignPage.php?pageID=<?php echo $pages['id']?>&displayID=<?php echo $_GET['displayID']?>" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"> Assign Page</a>
```

The issue is that when I click my submit link, it hits my php script and performs the update in my database but it's with the wrong page ID. It always uses the last pageID of the array that builds my options in the select.

How can I possibly use javascript in order to make sure the pageID in my  tag changes with each option select?

Comment: Please show us an example of the generated markup, so we can potentially debug to see the issue.

Comment: Actually, your link is sending the $pages['id'] on the get request for the pageID query param.  It's not taking the select into account at all.. :s

Comment: So how would I alter this so that it does? Again, the option value and text in the options list is correct as long as I can properly submit that in the link

Comment: You're link doesn't submit the form.  It's just a link.  If you want to use the select, you are going to have to submit the form, or make the get request with ajax that uses the data from the select.

Comment: Otherwise you'd have to write some script that changes the link href, onchange of the select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so first I added the id to the link so we can target it easily.

Next I added an id to the select for the same reason.

Then I created a change event handler for the select and added logic to it to first get the existing href, replace the pageID with the new value, and then set it back as the href on the link, so it keeps the displayID parameter.

I removed the php parts so it could be tested in the runnable snippet.

```js
document.getElementById('pageToAssign').addEventListener('change', function() {
  var assignPage = document.getElementById('assignPage');
  var href = assignPage.getAttribute('href');
  
  assignPage.href = href.replace( /pageID=[^&]+/, 'pageID='+ this.value );
});
```

```html
<select name="pageToAssign" id="pageToAssign">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="43">43</option>
</select>

<a href="assignPage.php?pageID=0&displayID=67" class="btn btn-primary" id="assignPage" role="button"> Assign Page</a>
```

Comment: It seems like the syntax is incorrect somewhere in my page. It's broken within the link somewhere

Comment: I edited it to include the `"` at the end of the href that was missing

Comment: I did include that edit but still the syntax is broken for some reason

Comment: Ah, it was mssing > at the end of php tag

Comment: No actually it's still broken for some reason. The button no longer shows, just a string of text

Comment: Can you put an example of the generated markup in a fiddle or something so I can see it?

Comment: <a href="assignPage.php?pageID=327" id="assignPage" &displayid="4&quot;" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"> Assign Page</a>

This is showing in the console when I select something. The pageID is correct, but the entire link should be ```pageID=327&displayid=4

Comment: Oh, crud!  lol, I stuck the id right in the middle of the href, :s

Comment: Yeah I started moving it which worked on page load, but when I select and it updates the pageID it removed the displayID

Comment: So I'm still not sure how to structure that so that it works whether on page load or after select. Basically, each select should also make sure it appends the displayID as well

Comment: Updated with an actual event handler so it can keep the displayID field. @TomN.